# Property of Conditional Probability Multiple Additive Variables

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I am working to explore a property of conditional probability that I could use some assistance with. The general problem can be stated as

$$\Pr(a > b \mid z^*)$$

where $z = z^* + u$. So then

$$\Pr(a > b \mid [z-u])$$

In the second probability statement, is there a property that would allow for the term $u$ to distribute to the left of the $|$ or otherwise reduce.

In the current problem I am working with $u$ is unobserved. It has some expected values, such as $E(u)=0$ and $E(u'u) = \sigma^2$, but I do not know if that is helpful within this context.

Comment: Which are the random variables and constants in this expression?

Comment: Grant, sorry, I actually meant to add that. The fixed values in this case would be $a$ and also $z^*$. However, $z$, $u$, and $b$ are the random variables.